# How to fix : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit, while running Junit for a project

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Getting below exception while running Junit , Not sure which part of code leading to this issue:
(using ANT - 1.9.4, ANT_OPTS=-Xmx10G)
( )

```
Tests run: 544, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 10,258.816 sec

   [junit] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
   [junit]  at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:300)
   [junit]  at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
   [junit]  at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:387)
   [junit]  at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:958)
   [junit]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.PlainJUnitResultFormatter.endTestSuite(PlainJUnitResultFormatter.java:152)
   [junit]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.fireEndTestSuite(JUnitTestRunner.java:619)
   [junit]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:452)
   [junit]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:911)
   [junit]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:768)
```

The exception is thrown after the tests are run and test report generation starts.

This is how junit is configured:

```xml
<junit fork="yes" newenvironment="false" haltonfailure="no" failureproperty="junit.failure" printsummary="yes" maxmemory="10096m">
```

Comment: <junit fork="yes" newenvironment="false" haltonfailure="no" failureproperty="junit.failure" printsummary="yes" maxmemory="10096m">

Comment: Bad recursion may be?

Comment: Where to find ? Nothing in exception stack trace

Comment: Can you determing which test fails?

Comment: yes, the test failure is known

Comment: What if skip it?

Comment: Tried, not useful. The exception is thrown after the tests are run and test report generation starts

Comment: So skip more tests.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using ANT 1.9.4?

Your stacktrace matches the source code of [PlainJUnitResultFormatter](https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/rel/1.8.4/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/PlainJUnitResultFormatter.java#L152) in ANT version 1.8.4:

```
out.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
```

Whereas in the source code of [PlainJUnitResultFormatter](https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/rel/1.9.4/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/PlainJUnitResultFormatter.java#L152) in ANT version 1.9.4:

```
write(StringUtils.LINE_SEP);
```

there is no call of `String.getBytes()` where the exception occurs.

The reason to ask is this comment from the [ANT 1.9.4 release notes](https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/RELEASE-NOTES-1.9.4.html):

> - changes to JUnitTestRunner and PlainJUnitResultFormatter to make
>   OutOfMemoryErrors less likely.
>   Bugzilla Report 45536

So the solution would be to upgrade to ANT 1.9.4 or later